# Error: The condition Bad address (error #14) , fail to run Huntentoot on Clozure CL

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot, clozure-cl, usocket

I am trying to run hunchentoot on IBM power6 and only clozure cl is available on that platform. I have tried this :

1.lisp

```
(hunchentoot:start (make-instance 'hunchentoot:easy-acceptor :port 80))
(hunchentoot:define-easy-handler (say-yo :uri "/yo") (name)
  (setf (hunchentoot:content-type*) "text/plain")
  (format nil "Hey~@[ ~A~]!" name))
```

then I loaded it in ccl :

```
(T482:lisp/ccl/201907271334) # ./ccl/ppccl64 -I 0.img -l 1.lisp
> Error: The condition Bad address (error #14) during socket creation operation in bind occurred with errno: 0.
> While executing: USOCKET::RAISE-ERROR-FROM-ID, in process listener(1).
> Type :GO to continue, :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
> If continued: Skip loading "1.lisp"
> Type :? for other options.
1 >
```

And I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Try to use a different port number, for instance `:port 9091`.

Comment: I have tried it

Comment: Do you have permission to accept connections from on the device you’re using?

Comment: I am using it as root user , and iptable have been switched off , I am sure that all the ports I have tried were not occupied by other programs (checked by using lsof)